# Necessary and sufficient condition for sequence to be representable by a polynomial with integer coefficients

Tags: polynomials

I have derived a lemma for solving olympiad problems about whether some sequence S<sub>n</sub> (n from a contiguous set of integers WLOG containing 0) can be represented by a polynomial P(n) with integer coefficients. I would like to know if it is already well known. It is as follows:

We define D<sup>i</sup><sub>n</sub> (where i is a nonnegative integer), the i<sup>th</sup> level difference of the sequence S<sub>n</sub>, as follows:

D<sup>0</sup><sub>n</sub> = S<sub>n</sub>

D<sup>i</sup><sub>n</sub> = D<sup>i-1</sup><sub>n+1</sub>-D<sup>i-1</sup><sub>n</sub>

If n is from a finite set of size m, we can only define up to the m-1<sup>th</sup> level difference.

Then, there exists a polynomial P(n) with integer coefficients such that P(n) = S<sub>n</sub> if and only if all the elements of the sequence D<sup>i</sup> are divisible by i!. If n is from an infinite set, we also require that there exists some j such that for all k > j, D<sup>k</sup> consists only of zeroes.

---

To prove this, note that all polynomials with integer coefficients P(n) can be written in the form Σ C<sub>i</sub>*<sub>n</sub>P<sub>i</sub> (where C<sub>i</sub> are integer coefficients) using the division algorithm, with the converse being clearly true.

Then, as <sub>n</sub>P<sub>i</sub>=0 for n from 0 to i-1 and <sub>n</sub>P<sub>i</sub>=i! for n = i, for S<sub>n</sub>=<sub>n</sub>P<sub>i</sub>, D<sup>j</sup><sub>0</sub>=0 for j from 0 to i-1 and D<sup>i</sup><sub>0</sub>=i!. By induction on the degree of polynomial, D<sup>j</sup><sub>0</sub>=0 for j > i.

Using the property that the differences of the sum of sequences are equal to the sum of the differences of sequences, we obtain that for S<sub>n</sub> = P(n) = Σ C<sub>i</sub>*<sub>n</sub>P<sub>i</sub>, D<sup>i</sup><sub>0</sub>=C<sub>i</sub>*i!, which is divisible by i!. Thus, we have proven the "only if" part of the statement. To prove the "if" part of the statement, we construct Σ C<sub>i</sub>*<sub>n</sub>P<sub>i</sub> for a sequence S<sub>n</sub> by obtaining C<sub>i</sub> from dividing D<sup>i</sup><sub>0</sub> by i!. Since a sequence is completely defined by a column of differences, S<sub>n</sub> = Σ C<sub>i</sub>*<sub>n</sub>P<sub>i</sub>, and we obtain a polynomial with integer coefficients by expanding it.

---

Is this a well known lemma, and where can I find similar useful lemmas?

Comment: See e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial

Comment: That's it, thank you!